# Wordpress JSON API Tax in ids

Tags: json, wordpress, api

I have JSON Reponse https://yeti-adventures.com/wp-json/wp/v2/to_book showing me the Taxonomies in ids i need it to show me the taxonomies in slug or name : Example ba_language 0: 106 & 1: 107 where in https://yeti-adventures.com/wp-json/wp/v2/ba_language it is defined the ids with names and slug ?

looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

solved by using embed&expand from WP documentation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).